# How to create LLVM Array type using AllocaInst?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-c++-api

I want to create LLVM ArrayType on stack so I wanted to use `AllocaInst (Type *Ty, Value *ArraySize=nullptr, const Twine &Name="", Instruction *InsertBefore=nullptr)`. The problem is I don't understand this interface. I guessed that `Ty` will be something like `ArrayType::get(I.getType(), 4)`, but what should I give for `ArraySize`. Furthermore, it requires `Value*`, so it confused me a lot.

Either I misunderstood llvm alloc or I need to provide a llvm constant as a value for array size. If I have to give the constant, isn't it little bit redundant since `ArrayType` contains the numElement as an information.

As an example line of code, the way I am trying to:

```
AllocaInst* arr_alloc = new AllocaInst(ArrayType::get(I.getType(), num)
                                       /*, What is this parameter for?*/,
                                       "",
                                       funcEntry.getFirstInsertionPt());
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I is the type of the array elements such as:

```
Type* I = IntegerType::getInt32Ty(module->getContext());
```

Then you can create an ArrayType of `num` elements:

```
ArrayType* arrayType = ArrayType::get(I, num);
```

This type can be used in an AllocInstr as following:

```
AllocaInst* arr_alloc = new AllocaInst(
    arrayType, "myarray" , funcEntry
//             ~~~~~~~~~
// -> custom variable name in the LLVM IR which can be omitted,
//    LLVM will create a random name then such as %2.
);
```

This example will yield the following LLVM IR instruction:

```
%myarray = alloca [10 x i32]
```

**EDIT**
Also it seems like you are allowed to pass a variable array size to the AllocInstr as following:

```
Type* I = IntegerType::getInt32Ty(module->getContext());
auto num = 10;
auto funcEntry = label_entry;

ArrayType* arrayType = ArrayType::get(I, num);

AllocaInst* variable = new AllocaInst(
  I, "array_size", funcEntry
);

new StoreInst(ConstantInt::get(I, APInt(32, 10)), variable, funcEntry);

auto load = new LoadInst(variable, "loader", funcEntry);

AllocaInst* arr_alloc = new AllocaInst(
  I, load, "my_array", funcEntry
);
```

Comment: I am kind of aware of this usage, but there is also an `ArraySize` parameter which is `Value*`, maybe it is not understandable from my question but I didn't understand the purpose of this parameter while using with `ArrayType`.

Comment: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'llvm::AllocaInst'

Comment: The `llvm::AllocaInst` API has been changed due to addition of the the address space to the constructor: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/9e362bb0eb52732cd9224d02bb7ce613bb47c1fc/llvm/include/llvm/IR/Instructions.h#L78-L91

Comment: @DenisBlank, "address space of 0, which corresponds to a Von Neumann architecture that has code and data in the same space." (https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html)